# What idioms are similar to "being pissed off" (e.g. really upset)?

Tags: idiom

In American English we can be "pissed off" or "really pissed". What idioms does Esperanto have to describe a state of being very upset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many expressions related to anger - beyond *kolera* and *kolerega*. Here are a few I found after a brief check in PIV.

- boli de kolero<sup>B</sup>
- bolas kolero en lia koro
- ĉe tiu demando la sango ekbolis en li<sup>B</sup>.
- eksplodi de furiozo, de kolero
- li eksplodis, dirante ke […]<sup>Z</sup>.
- mi estas tute furioza, ke mi staras kiel malpravulo, dum mi estas prava<sup>Z</sup>
- flama kolero<sup>Z</sup>

As a side note, notice that the definition of *furiozi* is **not** *esti furioza*, but rather it's ***agi*** furioze. It's always necessary to use care when expressing adjectives as verbs.

Answer (score 5):

The language is relatively idiom free because it is supposed to be international in nature.

Pissed off = **Kolerega - Mi estas kolerega**

Comment: All languages have idioms. Being an international language doesn't hamper this at all  "ne krokodilu" ONLY makes sense in Esperanto and is an idiom. Furthermore idioms help bind people of a culture together. They're like inside jokes, and shared pieces of communal history. Being "pissed off" is not identical to being "very upset".

Comment: @masukomi In that case, I don't think there is a matching idiom in Esperanto

Comment: Lumo5 is correct that the language is *relatively* idiom-free. Yes, there are some – *krokodili* and *prifajfi* spring immediately to mind – but really not many at all.

There's plenty of figurative use of language, metaphors, similes, allusions, irony, litotes, parisosis, and the like; but idioms, whose meaning by definition is non-obvious to someone who knows the individual words but not the expression as a whole, are anathema to a language whose fundamental purpose is to facilitate communication as a learned second language.

Comment: "idioms ... are anathema to a language whose fundamental purpose is to facilitate communication as a learned second language." - I see why someone would come to that conclusion, but to accept that means you can't build an Esperanto community / culture because all communities / cultures have internal knowledge and behavior that are weird / senseless to outsiders.

Comment: @masukomi What I was told is that Esperanto doesn't have many idioms because idioms are based on culture, and Esperanto has a huge variety of cultures that spans the world. Idioms would therefore be cryptic from one region to another, and cause a hindrance of communication

Comment: yes, that's why you don't *import* idioms. That's not a reason to not create idioms that are native to Esperanto.